# Automatic symlink to latest folder

Tags: files, filesystems, symlink

Is there a way in Linux to automatically maintain a symlink to the latest version of a file/folder in a certain location?

My use case:

- I generate datasets with unique job names, then write them to a 'results' folder
- I manually recreate a symlink to the latest version, naming it 'current'
- I can then always know 'current' refers to the most recent dataset
- This doesn't need to be perfectly instantaneous - accuracy on the order of seconds is acceptible.

I realise this can be achieved with a bash script and cron, but am wondering if there's a filesystem/OS feature that's more elegant.

Comment: use inotifywait -m or alike to trigger the script on event.